# Is it possible to do a server-only rename in TFS source control?

Tags: version-control, tfs

As of late, my team and I have been hard at work turning our inherited source code into something we can live with. Part of this process is to make the source control image look a little more like what most people might expect to find when browsing a repository.

The original structure contains a branch called "Branches", the contents of which are what one would find in a "Tags" folder in systems like Subversion. Since "Branches" is a bit too non-specific for my tastes, I wanted to change it to "Tags" -- but it would seem that I cannot do that unless I create a workspace mapped to the root of the repository and then create a working copy from it. On this project that is a **huge** file transfer (lots of old tags).

Please tell me that I have just overlooked the obvious and should really spend more time reading the instructions. Is there no simple way to do this without pulling everything to the client first? I really enjoy most aspects of TFS, but this is something that would have taken 15 seconds or less in Subversion -- so I hope I'm just missing something.

Thanks in advance to any responders.

Comment: Just wondering why you do not like the name "Branches".  The term "Branches" is commonly used in TFS installations where you might see the term "Tags" in a Subversion repository.

Comment: It might just be an old prejudice on my part. "Tags" seems to have a little more specific connotation. I expect to find a collection of previous releases in such a folder. "Branches" is just a hair on the general side for my tastes. Are they development branches, hotfix, both, none? Granted, the branching documentation for your project should spell this out, but I'm kind of fond of layouts that impart as much meaning at a glance as possible.

Comment: @Jon: Tags and Branches are both pretty generic..  We tend to be a little more specific in our folder naming scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to get the whole folder but you need to get the folder itself. You can't do this from within the IDE but you can from the command-line:

```
tf get c:\dev\
```

Because we haven't specified the /recursive option it will only get the immediate children of c:\dev\, which would be folders such as trunk and branches.

For there you can rename the folder:

```
tf rename c:\dev\branches c:\dev\tags
```

And then check-in the rename.

Regards,

William D. Bartholomew (Team System MVP)

Comment: Thank you, sir. I seem to get in the mode of using just the GUI in studio and TFPT from the command line, so I forget that TF is more tunable than the GUI.